# Can the underlying type of an Objective-C enum be specified?

Tags: objective-c, enums

I was surprised to discover that Xcode does not issue an error for the following code, which is invalid in C:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    FLAG_A = 1,
    FLAG_B = 2,
    FLAG_C = 4
} MyFlags;
```

This appears to make `NSUInteger` the underlying type of the `MyFlags` enum, very similar to C#'s syntax for setting the underlying type of an enum.

Does this syntax do what it appears, or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a feature borrowed from C++11 used to ensure a specific size of the enum. It allows to use enums in the public API of frameworks without having to fear that the ABI will eventually break.

[Clang implements this feature](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_fixed_enum) and allows its use in Objective-C as a language extension.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine in objective c. you can set any value for these params in an enum.